# Change size of polymer-elements (checkbox)

Tags: css, polymer

I tried to change the size of the paper-checkbox by changing the width and height attributes in my css-file, and by using transform: scale(2,2)

Scale makes it blurry, width and height only changes the clickable area.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: sure, but it's nothing fancy.. I included webcomponents and the paper-elements. the code is: <paper-check-box></paper-check-box>...

Comment: all of paper-checkbox's code can be found here: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

I think you found the correct solution already. You can't change the resolution, therefore there's nothing you can do.

For those who don't care about the blur, here's the css:

```
paper-checkbox
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In polymer 1.0 and paper-checkbox 1.2 it works with this simple style

```
paper-checkbox {
    --paper-checkbox-size: 30px;
}
```

When I was first trying to use paper-checkbox bower installed version 1.0 for me. And this version had issues. So maybe this might be the case for you as well.